# Getting the error "cannot add an entity that already exists." while inserting a table's value in to DB without procedure

Tags: c#, linq

I am inserting a list of records to the DB table with Linq to sql like this:

```
//my DataContext Class
 using (VTMMedicalDBDataContext objVTMMedicalDBDataContext = new VTMMedicalDBDataContext())
 {
     ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> objTimeZones = null;

     objTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

     if (objTimeZones.Count > 0)
     {
         //List<TimeZoneMaster> listTimeZones = new List<TimeZoneMaster>();
         TimeZoneMaster objTimeZoneMaster = new TimeZoneMaster();

         foreach (var timezone in objTimeZones.ToList())
         {

             objTimeZoneMaster.TimeZoneName = timezone.DisplayName;

             var localName = timezone.DisplayName;

             objTimeZoneMaster.TimeZoneOffsetInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(timezone.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes);                      


             objVTMMedicalDBDataContext.TimeZoneMasters.InsertOnSubmit(objTimeZoneMaster);
             objVTMMedicalDBDataContext.SubmitChanges();


         }

     }
}
```

I have a primary key but I have already made it as AutoGeneratd as true in DBML Nullable as false.Still I am not able to get rid of it...Please suggest some way around.

Comment: What type is your primary key?

Comment: @James: It is integer type.

Comment: I assume you have it also auto-increment at DB level?

Comment: Hmm...which backend DB are you using? I assume it's SQL server but just for clarity. Also, you are getting at least 1 record inserted what is the primary key value for that? Is it being generated?

Comment: @James Yes James,I am getting one record inserted for which ID is 1 but I believe it is not updating the ID at server side because just checking the values before 2nd InsertOnSubmit,I find ID as only only at aspx.cs file end..!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally After Much hassle I got my answer with a new concept..

**For all those facing similar problems,here is a clear solution:**

*You need to create the object of the 'Table' class(which object you want to update in DB),
inside the **loop**(**for each,for or any other..)so that same record is not updated and each object uses a different memory location(as the local instance gets destroyed inside the loop only..)***

Comment: haha of course, I was too focussed on the DBML to actually look at your code! +1 well done for solving it. Once you insert the record it becomes attached to the DataContext so you can't re-use it.

Comment: This saved me !!! Kudos buddy !! I have a similar implementation of adding to database from a list. Was getting exactly the same error as you faced and after 6 hours of debugging I am finally through :)

Answer (score 3):

> I have a primary key but I already made it as AutoGenerated as true in DBML

That's fine, however, have you made the field auto-generated at database level? AutoGenerated at DBML level won't actually generate any values for you, it just indicates to the model that the value will be generated by the storage provider (so it probably omits sending it as part of the query).

Comment: I couldn't get your last line in the answer...Do you want me to pass O as default value to that integer column??

Comment: @RahulRanjan "*Do you want me to pass 0 as default value*" - no that wasn't what I was saying. I have removed that line as it was complicating the answer. When you add new records via MGMT Studio does the primary key increment? Is this purely a Linq2SQL issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update table to have that column with identity value (autoincrement).

Then update your DBML model-> Delete the table from DBML designer, refresh your table at server explorer and drag and drop the table object again. Generate the project and it should work nice.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can call stored procedure inside db which will do the insert:
[Updating database by using stored procedures.](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 0):

using (VTMMedicalDBDataContext objVTMMedicalDBDataContext = new VTMMedicalDBDataContext())
 {
     ReadOnlyCollection objTimeZones = null;

```
 objTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

 if (objTimeZones.Count > 0)
 {
     //List<TimeZoneMaster> listTimeZones = new List<TimeZoneMaster>();


     foreach (var timezone in objTimeZones.ToList())
     {
          TimeZoneMaster objTimeZoneMaster = new TimeZoneMaster();

         objTimeZoneMaster.TimeZoneName = timezone.DisplayName;

         var localName = timezone.DisplayName;

         objTimeZoneMaster.TimeZoneOffsetInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(timezone.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes);                      


         objVTMMedicalDBDataContext.TimeZoneMasters.InsertOnSubmit(objTimeZoneMaster);
         objVTMMedicalDBDataContext.SubmitChanges();


     }

 }
```

}

Comment: Please explain why your solution addresses the original asker's question.