# Unable add an entity that already exists

Tags: c#, linq

I get the error "Cannot add an entity that already exists" on submit changes but i set a new ID which is unique on every record (primary key)

```
protected void lbtnAddEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExcelImportDataContext dc = new ExcelImportDataContext();
        DataTable dtCustomers = (DataTable)ViewState["dtCustomers"];

        Customer obj = new Customer();

        int count = 0;


            if (dtCustomers != null && dtCustomers.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dtCustomers.Columns.Add("-Select-");

                foreach (DataRow row in dtCustomers.Rows)
                {
                    row["-Select-"] = string.Empty;

                    obj.name= row[id1.SelectedValue].ToString();
                    obj.surename= row[id2.SelectedValue].ToString();
                    obj.phoneNumber= row[id3.SelectedValue].ToString();


                dc.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(obj);

                    dc.SubmitChanges();


                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the error "cannot add an entity that already exists." while inserting a table's value in to DB without procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684748/getting-the-error-cannot-add-an-entity-that-already-exists-while-inserting-a)

Answer (score 0):

Oups my bad, I had `Customer obj = new Customer();` out of the foreach  loop

RESOLVED!

You are than welcome to suggest me something to change.

```
int count = 0;

        if (dtCustomers != null && dtCustomers.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dtCustomers.Columns.Add("-Select-");
            foreach (DataRow row in dtCustomers.Rows)
            {
                Customer obj = new Customer();
                row["-Select-"] = string.Empty;
```