# Save picture Path with LINQ in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I wanna save the picture path using LINQ inside the data base sql

But with errors

"Cant add an entity that already exists."

I got.
How do I fix this error.
 Incidentally, there is a DataBase field of "NVarChar"  type.

My Code

```
    private void BtnSave_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameAx=TxtId.Text;


        string addres = Application.StartupPath + "\\PicStu\\" + nameAx + ".jpg";


        var UpdateLINQ = (from rows in db.InfoStudents where rows.Id == Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text) select rows).FirstOrDefault();

        UpdateLINQ.ImageStudent = addres;
            db.InfoStudents.InsertOnSubmit(UpdateLINQ);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Save Sucses");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the error "cannot add an entity that already exists." while inserting a table's value in to DB without procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684748/getting-the-error-cannot-add-an-entity-that-already-exists-while-inserting-a)

Comment: I don't understand this text. Explain more.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684748/getting-the-error-cannot-add-an-entity-that-already-exists-while-inserting-a

Answer (score 0):

Try without this line

```cs
db.InfoStudents.InsertOnSubmit(UpdateLINQ);
```

[some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-update-rows-in-the-database)

Comment: The problem of what is. I got very edited but useless

Answer (score 0):

i find

```
var update = db.InfoStudents.Where(o => o.Id == Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (update != null)
        {
            update.ImageStudent = addres;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not ok");
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
```